# When was "what's cooking" first used?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

Does anyone know when the expression "what's cooking" began to be used in the United States? I'm interested because I'm writing a novel set in 1933.

A [contributor on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-did-the-expression-whats-cooking-come) found examples from 1939. Are there any examples earlier than that?

Answer (score 4):

GDoS (Green’s Dictionary of Slang) has usage examples from the ‘20s, so you can probably use it safely in your context:

[What’s cooking:](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/gtx3nby#kfwsw2y)

> lit. ‘what’s going on?’, i.e. what is happening?; thus negative response nothing cooking.
>
> 1926 Maines & Grant Wise-crack Dict. 11/2: *Nothing cooking – Nothing doing.*
>
> 1944 H. Brown Walk in Sun 77: *What’s cooking, Jack?*